# Issue using os.walk(). is this method not feasible?

Tags: python-3.x, os.walk

I have more folders i want to pick up using os.wakl which eventually have same end pattern , i.e simv.vdb so i am using the below code

```
p=input("path::")
exclude="LOGS"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(p):
       for dir in dirs:
               dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude]
               if (dir.endswith("simv.vdb")):
                       result.append(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(root,dir)))
```

but i am only able to pick up around 1400 files out of 2000 existing ones. and same is happening if folders or more or less. can someone please check whether my code need any up-gradation? or any tips to improve this  will be helpful. thanks.

Comment: why not use `glob` module?

Comment: @bigbounty as per my knowledge, i used glob for only current directory. but i require here to search multiple dirs. if you know how to use glob for multiple folders, please provide the method. it'll be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

issue was with the `dirs[:]` line. i put that line before looping of dirs starts and issue is resolved.